# Replace System.getProperty inside constructor to yml

Tags: java, spring

I know this is very basic java question. I m unable to find solution for replacing a property defined using System.getProperty() inside constructor to yml file and set it using commandline property.

I am instanciaing that bean using spring xml but can I inject a yml defined property to. Its constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This particular bean needed to read properties at instantiation, so I had to use spring's  or @Values tag to inject my property value.